# Issue of vue setting value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set up the assignment of the data to the object, but when you try to do it with a v-model and an external function for some reason, the fields are updated in all the child elements instead of one update. here's the code in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-ardinghelli-6bvpf) and [Sanbox with v-model](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-thunder-k9nin)

Comment: your code is not using v-model, your using `onchange.prop`, then trying to match by id etc.. just use v-model then all that matching code can be removed, like 90% of your js

Comment: sidenote, if you need to use `$forceUpdate` your doing it wrong

Comment: I use forceupdate because fields update nested array are not working at their filling, as well vmodel betrayed the same result as in the example. original code was built on the v-model but adding functions was an attempt to correct the error due to which the field changes in one object will automatically apply to all. what actually happens in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [v-model one](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-thunder-k9nin),

change

```
this.template_['default_' + this.iterable++] = Object.assign(this.template_default);
```

to

```
this.$set(this.template_, 'default_' + this.iterable++, Object.assign({}, this.template_default));
```